# ECS Docker Container get env variable running cron

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker, cron, environment-variables

I am running a docker container through AWS ECS and am attempting to use an environment variable set by the ecs-agent. Specfically I am grabbing

```
$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

I am logged into the container as root and when I check env the above is present. However when I check the env using sudo the environment variable is not present.

I am running a python script that uses this variable and when I run the script as root the script is able to find the environment variable fine and executes successfully. However I need to run this script using cron. Thus far I have not been able to get cron to run and access roots environment variables. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by dumping that environment variable to a file. Then I sourced that file from the script executed by my cron job.

For example, in my `Dockerfile` I have something like:

```
CMD echo "export AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" > /src/containerCreds.sh && ...
```

Then, my cron job script sources the file that contains the exported env var.

```
. /src/conatinerCreds.sh
```